# Cannot modify numpy 2d array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to modify the `boolarr` numpy array depending on the contents of the `reducedMatrix` array.
It is supposed to change the boolean value of the `boolarr` to False if `reducedMatrix` is not a 0 or a -1.

```
reducedMatrix = np.load(reducedweightmatrix)

boolarr = np.ones(shape=(len(reducedMatrix),len(reducedMatrix)),dtype="bool")

for y,yelement in enumerate(reducedMatrix):
    for x,xelement in enumerate(yelement):
        if(xelement != -1 and xelement != 0):
            print(x)
            print(y)
            print("\n")
            boolarr[y,x] == False

print(reducedMatrix)
print(boolarr)
```

The log keeps on showing the following:

```
[[-1  5  5  0  0]
 [ 5 -1  0  0  0]
 [ 5  0 -1  0  5]
 [ 0  0  0 -1  0]
 [ 0  0  5  0 -1]]
[[ True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True]
 [ True  True  True  True  True]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to edit `boolarray` elementwise when you can just create it in one vectorized line:

```
boolarray = (reducedMatrix == 0) | (reducedMatrix == -1)
# array([[ True, False, False,  True,  True],
#        [False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#        [False,  True,  True,  True, False],
#        [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
#        [ True,  True, False,  True,  True]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change

```
boolarr[y,x] == False
```

into

```
boolarr[y,x] = False
```